# Another trying to access array offset on value of type int

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is part of a search script that I built for my inventory database. Here is my code:

```
$sum = 0;
$result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM ".DB_HOME_BOOK." WHERE owner_id='".$userdata['user_id']."' AND title LIKE '%$query%' OR author LIKE '%$query%' OR format LIKE '%$query%' OR publisher LIKE '%$query%' OR year LIKE '%$query%' OR isbn LIKE '%$query%' OR value LIKE '%$query%'");
$nrows = dbrows($result);
$sum += (intval($nrows['value']));
```

The 'value' db field is an interger holding the book value. $nrows gives me the record count holding a money amount in the value field. That works fine. Here is the code portion that displays the information:

```
$formatted_value = "$".number_format( (float) $sum, 2, '.', '');
echo "<tr><td class='srch-total' align='center'>".$locale['his_1433']."$num_rows</td><td class='srch-total' align='center'>".$locale['his_1425']."$nrows</td><td class='srch-total' align='center'>".$locale['his_1424']."$formatted_value</td></tr>\n";
```

My CMS is php-fusion latest version 9.00.110. I have tried many different scenarios to obtain the total value of found books to no avail. The $formatted_value shows 0 with the error in my error log. The source of the error is this:
$sum += (intval($nrows['value'])); I don't understand how to code what needs to be done to get the desired output w/o error. I have looked at all the questions here that are related to the error but none so far are applicable to my unique situation.

Comment: Since `dbrows` returns the `count` of the rows returned by your query, it's not an array. You need to use a different method to actually get the rows, loop them while a `while` and then make the sum within the loop

Comment: My friend and I whom I've been collaborating with for a few years now, figured this out as well and we now have the problem solved and working perfectly. By combining a mysql query and a mysqli query on the same page. We have taken precautions against injections. I can't really show the whole script as it is proprietary to our system and the module is only accessible by user id to logged users. It is not even visible to the public. So this question is solved and can be closed.